# Código de alguns branchs sumiram após merge

Tags: git, merge

Estou com uma situação bem esquisita (provavelmente vacilo né...) aqui no meu repositório.

Tenho um branch de `DEV` e vários outros de features e bugs.

A cada branch de feature ou bug, fazemos o merge com branch `DEV`.

Trabalhamos em 2 Devs neste projeto, eu, sempre antes de fazer o `merge`, faço um `pull` no branch de Dev. Ai depois faço os merges. O outro dev, aparentemente fez um `git fecth` antes de fazer o merge, não faço ideia se isso implicou em algo, mas alguns dos branches que eu já havia feito merge em DEV simplesmente não consta o código no branch de DEV.

Rodei o comando `git log -all`, que se entendi bem, mostra os branchs que fazem parte do branch selecionado no momento, então, com o branch de DEV selecionado, ao rodar este comando, constam os branchs cujos códigos estão ausente.

Preciso entender o que fizemos de errado...

Eu tenho o "código perdido" nos respectivos branchs (local e remoto), então selecionei um dos branchs e ao tentar fazer o merge novamente, dá uma mensagem dizendo que está atualizado (`Already up to date.`)

Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Servidor privado, GitHub ou similares?

Comment: Local é local, remoto é remoto, no remoto vc pode ter branchs que não existem no remoto e vice-versa, não tem muito o q ajudarmos, talvez vc olhando de trás pra frente o log até ver o ponto que o tal branch sumido deixou de "existir" ou ser "logado".

Comment: bitbucket privado @JonathandeToni

Comment: talvez tenha me expressado mal @GuilhermeNascimento, não foi o branch que sumiu, quis dizer que o código de alguns branches não constam no branche de DEV, que é o qual "recebe" os merges.

queria muito entender como fizemos essa cagada..., mas tão importante quanto, é saber como faço para refazer estes merges, pois tenho os branches com os códigos que preciso, mas ao tentar fazer o merge com Dev, diz que já está atualizado.

Comment: Da uma olhada no Bitbucket, vê se as branchs ainda estão lá, se estiver, problema é somente local. Ai cai no comentário do @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: @JonathandeToni, os branches de features e bugs adicionados constam local e remoto. sabe o que posso fazer conseguir fazer o merge novamente?

Comment: Ainda sim recomendo o método do @GuilhermeNascimento de rever o log de trás para frente, assim você consegue achar o momento certo de onde a cagada foi feita

Comment: Quati_Maldito Se não constam no branch então vc não os commitou, se não fez o commit então não existem lá e nem nunca existiram e não tem como pegar algo q vc não salvou (cc @JonathandeToni)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, cara, valeu pela ajuda, mas isso tá bem louco para alguém que não manja muito como eu..., os commits constam no remote. Eu desenvolvo em um ambiente local, então desenvolvi vários branches, e fazendo o commit e merge com DEV a cada vez q terminasse o job. Ai gerava um novo branche com base em Dev, e seguia o jogo, até que na sexta-feira última, o outro Dev fez um merge com o branch que ele estava desenvolvendo e aí "sumiram" os códigos que tinham sido mesclados (merge).

Comment: Cara, uma recomendação, começa a utilizar ferramentas como o git-flow, fica mais fácil de trabalhar, são poucos comandos e faz tudo certinho. Para quem não está acostumado, é uma ótima entrada!

Comment: Se constam no remoto então os código estão lá, faz um outro branch local como o nome RECUPERAR e faz o rollback até o ponto que vc precisa pegar os tais arquivos, copia tudo o que precisa, deleta o branch, pega o que copiou e ajusta no seu branch de edição, pronto :)

Answer (score 2):

Analisar problemas específicos de merge são complicados sem entender **exatamente** quais comandos foram dados, que ordem foram realizados, se existiu conflito, se alguém tem permissão para fazer *force push*, se os usuários podem commitar direto na branch `dev`, se o que sumiu foi código dentro de classes existentes, se sumiram até mesmo classes novas, etc.

Como o git é uma ferramenta muito flexível, existem várias maneiras diferentes de chegar nos mesmos resultados (bons ou não).

Mas melhor do que dar o peixe, é ensinar a pescar. E podemos também tirar algumas conclusões do que você disse.

Como o `merge` foi identificado como já feito na branch de `dev`, isto significa que o merge ocorreu mas algo se perdeu durante este merge ou depois dele. A maior possibilidade que vejo é que o merge foi realizado, **ocorreu algum conflito** e quem resolveu conflito escolheu considerar apenas as alterações da branch dele.

## Como analisar

Tente identificar um ponto no histórico do seu repositório onde o código ainda estava na branch pelo git log:

```
git log
```

A partir dele, vasculhe o histórico procurando em que momento o código sumiu. Você pode ir fazendo isto fazendo um checkout direto para cada commit no histórico e vendo o código daquele momento no repositório:

```
git checkout eR43yUi
```

(para voltar ao `HEAD`, faça `git checkout dev`)

Se tiver alguma dúvida entre as alterações de dois commits, você pode ver as diferenças entre os commits com o `git diff`:

```
git diff eR43yUi..7yaoljM
```

Veja a diferença entre os commits antes e depois de cada merge realizado, pois provavelmente foi neste ponto que ocorreu o problema.

Se ver algum commit mencionando algum tipo de `revert`, veja se não foi este commit a causa do problema. Alguém pode ter revertido algum commit da branch "mergeada" com `git revert` após feito o merge.

Answer (score 2):

Para constar para o caso de alguém passar por algo semelhante.

Concluímos que um dos devs da equipe fez uma feature nova e a base disso foi um branch antigo, sem as atualizações das últimas semanas e as enviou "matando" tudo que os demais devs fizeram.

Para resolver o problema, segui a [ideia do Guilherme Nascimento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/435091/c%C3%B3digo-de-alguns-branchs-sumiram-ap%C3%B3s-merge#comment841479_435091), fiz um "rollback" até um update antes do branch que "matou" as alterações, e usei o comando:

```
git checkout HEAD~1
```

Onde o 1 representa quantos commits você quer retroceder o ponteiro no `HEAD`.

By: https://brorlandi.github.io/git-desfazendo-commits

Obrigado a todos que ajudaram.